# why is the ORTOOLS guided local search, that starts with a feasible solution considered constraint programming?

Tags: optimization, constraint-programming, or-tools

I'm using the [ORTOOLS](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/constraint_solver/routing/) library for solving a VRP problem. I give it an initial feasible solution to my problem, satisfying all the constraints of my problem but sub-optimal. Then ORTOOLS performs a GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH heuristic, continuously perturbing parts of my solution (possibly making it infeasible at times) until it hopefully reaches a better solution than my initial solution.

Why is it using a [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) solver? My understanding is that classic constraint programming starts with an infeasible (possibly empty) solution, propagates the constraints to narrow the domains of my variables until reaching a stationary state, and then makes a decision. Then it iterates again until solving the problem or backtracks if reaching a dead-end (think SUDOKU).

In what way are these capabilities (propagation, backtracking) needed when making the small perturbations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two reasons.

1) The initial solution heuristics is a combination of fast LS heuristic search and standard constraint programming search.

2) The whole local search implementation is build on top of a traditional constraint programming solver and uses constraints and propagators to validate solution, and complete them.

See: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/920

Comment: thanks! but in (2) - we don't need a whole lot of propagation when we do the standard step of relocate_pair, right? I mean: all variables already **have a value**, it's not that we can use propagation to narrow down the domains of their possible values?

Comment: It depends. When filters are perfect, you do not need propagation, and you do not want to call propagation. But in some cases, having perfect filters is not possible/implemented/worthwhile, and you rely on propagation to validate solutions.  There are also cases, in particular with scheduling sub-models where you rely on constraints and search to solve the residual model.